# KONY - IOException occurred while obtaining response: feed.foxnews: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: temenos-quantum

I am newbie to Kony trying to do a sample service call and i am seeing the below error, Can you please help what could have possible gone wrong with this.

When i click on the getResponse button in studio i see below error, I have checked project settings and kony server is selected and configured. thanks in advnace for all your help.

Error :- IOException occurred while obtaining response: feed.foxnews: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete existing service and configure the kony server, create the service again and should work.