# IOException in KonyRestClient executeConnection refused

Tags: android, temenos-quantum

I initialised the `KonyClient` like below

```
public void initializeKonyClient(Context mContext){
    Context context = mContext;

    KonyClient myClient = new KonyClient();
    myClient.acceptSelfSignedCertificates();

    try {
        myClient.initAsync(mContext,appkey,appsecret,serviceURL,
        new InitCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JSONObject response) {
                Log.e("InitCallback","Success");
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(KonyException error) {
                Log.e("InitCallback", "Failed");
            }
        });
    }
    catch (KonyException exception) {

    }
}
```

after this I call one `API`. Previously its working fine, but I keep having an error `The IOException in KonyRestClient executeConnection to URL refused`. My Internet is okay. Is there anyway to solve this and why it keeps on displaying? Thank you.

Comment: I think this may [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34678420/7073808) help you

Comment: @VikasTiwari thank you i'll check it out.